# Jquery does not run correctly when page is not refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC page that show and hide some text-boxes depend on drop Down value change using Jquery. The page is working by itself but when I put under the menu when I go to other menu option and comeback to this it shows all the text boxes. this is my Jquery code in the view:

```
   function toggleDIvDisplay(e) {
       if (!e)
          e = '';

     $('button.search').toggle(e != '');
     $('#divAppName').toggle(e == 1);

     $('#divSSN').toggle(e == 2);

    $('#divRemref').toggle(e == 3);



}


 $(document).ready(function () {


    $('button.search').click(function (evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();

        var container = $('#customer-results');
        container.hide();

        $('table tbody', container).empty();

          var searchMethod = $('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.SearchMethod)').val();

        switch (searchMethod) {
            case '1':
                getByFirstNameAndLastName();
                break;
            case '2':

                getBySSN();
                break;
            case '3':
                getByRemRef();

                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    });

     toggleDIvDisplay();

    });
```

This is my Textboxes and search button in view:

```
    <div class="clearfix"  style="margin-top:20px">
    Search By:
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SearchMethod,    Model.AvailableSearchMethods, new { onchange = "toggleDIvDisplay(this.value)" })


   </div>
   <div id="divAppName" class="pull-left" style="margin-top:35px">
   First Name:
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)

   Last Name:
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)

  </div>
 <div id="divSSN" class="pull-left" style="margin-top:35px">
 SSN:
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SSN)
  </div>
     <div id="divRemref" class="pull-left" style="margin-top:35px">
           RemRef:

   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RemoteRefNumber)
  </div>
  <div class="pull-left" style="margin-top:35px;margin-left:50px">
<button class="btn btn-success search pull-left">Search</button>
</div>
```

and this is the link in the menu:

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Application Document Lookup", "Search", "Doc")</li>
```

Comment: 1) You don't have any AJAX in your code above. 2) When you navigate away/back you reset your page so you'll need to maintain the element states e.g. with cookies or [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

Answer (score 0):

```
      var searchMethod = $('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.SearchMethod)').val();
```

the @Html is rendered on the server side (MVC).

Only after it is rendered and sent to your browser, your jQuery can see it.
Eventually, if you Inspect your page you will not find anything with an Id like this.

it should be $("#ID OF THE DROP DOWN HERE")

On the otherhand, jQuery cannot run the functions on your Model, so you have to either your View Or your jQuery to do so, but not both.